# How to relaunch Finder Application in cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder

I need to relaunch my finder application in my cocoa app with sandbox support.I have tried like

**Attempt 1:**

```
[[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/killall"
                              arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Finder", nil]] waitUntilExit];
```

its not supported in sandbox. Its shows *`killall: warning: kill -TERM 7833: Operation not permitted`* error.

**Attempt 2:**

```
NSDictionary *error = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\" to restart"];
    [script executeAndReturnError:&error];
```

its is also not permitted in sandbox.

Is there any to relaunch Finder Application in my app with sandbox support?

Comment: It might help if you provide information on why exactly you're looking to restart the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html).

> With App Sandbox you cannot send Apple events to other apps unless you
>   configure a scripting-targets entitlement or an apple-events temporary
>   exception entitlement.

**Entitlement key**

- com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events

**Capability**

- Enables sending of Apple events to one or more destination apps.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will not work, because Apple typically rejects apps from the Mac App Store with temporary exceptions for Finder.